# Filling in values in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose I have this data frame:

```
  times vals
1     1    2
2     3    4
3     7    6
```

set up with

```
foo <- data.frame(times=c(1,3,7), vals=c(2,4,6))
```

and I want this one:

```
  times vals
1     1    2
2     2    2
3     3    4
4     4    4
5     5    4
6     6    4
7     7    6
```

That is, I want to fill in all the times from 1 to 7, and fill in the vals from the latest time that is not greater than the given time.

I have some code to do it using dplyr, but it is ugly.  Suggestions for better?

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- merge(foo, data.frame(times=1:max(foo$times)), all.y=TRUE)
foo2 <- merge(foo, foo, by=c(), suffixes=c('', '.1'))

foo2 <- foo2 %>% filter(is.na(vals) & !is.na(vals.1) & times.1 <= times) %>%
  group_by(times) %>% arrange(-times.1) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(rn == 1) %>%
  mutate(vals = vals.1,
         rn = NULL,
         vals.1 = NULL,
         times.1 = NULL)

foo <- merge(foo, foo2, by=c('times'), all.x=TRUE, suffixes=c('', '.2'))
foo <- mutate(foo,
              vals = ifelse(is.na(vals), vals.2, vals),
              vals.2 = NULL)
```

Comment: `data.frame(time = 1:7, vals = foo$vals[findInterval(1:7, foo$times)])` will work for NAs since @eddi has deemed it such an important issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `dplyr` and `tidyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo %>%
 right_join(data_frame(times = min(foo$times):max(foo$times))) %>%
 fill(vals)
# Joining by: "times"
#   times vals
# 1     1    2
# 2     2    2
# 3     3    4
# 4     4    4
# 5     5    4
# 6     6    4
# 7     7    6
```

Comment: this will give incorrect results if `foo$vals` has `NA`'s to begin with

Comment: Not incorrect, just not a rolling join. You can do that, if you like: `if(any(is.na(foo$vals))){foo %>% slice(which(is.na(vals)):(which(is.na(vals)) + 1)) %>% right_join(data_frame(times = seq(.[seq(1, nrow(.), by = 2), 'times'], .[ifelse(nrow(.) > 1, seq(2, nrow(.), by = 2), 1), 'times']))) %>% bind_rows(anti_join(foo %>% right_join(data_frame(times = min(foo$times):max(foo$times))) %>% fill(vals), ., by = 'times')) %>% arrange(times)} else {foo %>% right_join(data_frame(times = min(foo$times):max(foo$times))) %>% fill(vals)}` though there's probably a more graceful way.

Comment: From OP: *"... and fill in the vals from the latest time that is not greater than the given time"* - this is basically the textbook definition of a rolling join. I'm not sure how you'd possibly interpret that to fill in NA's with previous non-NA values.

Comment: There are no `NA`s given. Given this operation imputes data, it would be somewhat odd to have them, and odder to leave them.

Comment: This answer **replaces existing** data if there are NA's, NOT imputes non-existent data. That's the issue. Replace `foo[2, 'vals'] = NA`, then run your answer and watch how you lose that information.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but you're arguing that `NA` is _not_ nonexistent data.

Comment: First of all of course `NA` is not *just* non-existent data. It can mean many other things. But even if it means non-existent data - `foo`, with `NA`, says at time 1, data was 2, then at time 3 there was no data, then at time 7 data was 6. If you fill in the rest of the times, the natural way to do that is "from time 1 to 2 data was 2, from time 3 to 6 there was no data, from time 7 on data was 6". Having no data is a measurement that's generally different from data being the same as before.

Answer (score 10):

This is a standard rolling join problem:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(foo)[.(1:7), on = 'times', roll = T]
#   times vals
#1:     1    2
#2:     2    2
#3:     3    4
#4:     4    4
#5:     5    4
#6:     6    4
#7:     7    6
```

The above is for devel version (1.9.7+), which is smarter about column matching during joins. For 1.9.6 you still need to specify column name for the inner table:

```
setDT(foo)[.(times = 1:7), on = 'times', roll = T]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and your comments on other answers about their limitations with respect to NAs. Just FYI, I don't like data.table (I find the syntax hard to read), so I lean towards solutions from "the Hadley-verse" (packages by Hadley Wickham, like tidyr, dplyr, ..), even with their limitations.

Comment: @dfrankow sure, np. Fwiw, here's a very simple way to read `data.table` syntax that will allow understanding 90% of the syntax. `d[i, j, by = b]` is read as "take `d`, apply `i`, then compute `j` by `b`".

Answer (score 6):

With `approx`:

```
data.frame(times = 1:7, 
           vals = unlist(approx(foo, xout = 1:7, method = "constant", f = 0)[2], use.names = F))

  times vals
1     1    2
2     2    2
3     3    4
4     4    4
5     5    4
6     6    4
7     7    6
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that! You could also just coerce to data.frame and change the names: `setNames(data.frame(approx(foo, xout = 1:7, method = "constant", f = 0)), names(foo))`

Comment: this suffers from the same issue as alistaire's solution - will fail if there are NA's to begin with

Comment: change `foo[2, 'vals'] = NA` and run it

Comment: whether it was in my original question or not, it's helpful to point out limitations or subtleties.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit longer and more verbose base R solution:

```
# calculate the number of repetitions needed for vals variable
reps <- c(with(foo, times[2:length(times)]-times[1:length(times)-1]), 1)

# get result
fooDoneIt <- data.frame(times = min(foo$times):max(foo$times),
              vals = rep(foo$vals, reps))
```